# Issue with PHP pop( ) function

Tags: c, stack

So I'm having an issue with my pop() function, when running my program, the first time I call the pop() function it returns the item no problem, but when it tries to pop the second item in succession, it fails. I can't seem to figure out why, is there something I'm missing in my function?

```
#define DEFAULT_CAPACITY 16

struct stack {
   size_t capacity;
   size_t size;
   stack_item *data;
};

stack *new_stack (void) {
   stack *this = malloc (sizeof (stack));
   assert (this != NULL);
   this->capacity = DEFAULT_CAPACITY;
   this->size = 0;
   this->data = calloc (this->capacity, sizeof (stack_item));
   assert (this->data != NULL);
   return this;
}

void free_stack (stack *this) {
   assert (empty_stack (this));
   free (this->data);
   free (this);
}

static bool full_stack (stack *this) {
  return this->size == this->capacity;
}

static void realloc_stack (stack *this) {
   size_t old_capacity = this->capacity;
   this->capacity *= 2;
   this->data = realloc (this->data, this->capacity);
   memset (this->data + old_capacity, 0, old_capacity);
   assert (this->data != NULL);
}


void push_stack (stack *this, stack_item item) {
   if (full_stack (this)) realloc_stack (this);
   //increase size of stack
   this->data[this->size] = item;
   this->size++;
}

stack_item pop_stack (stack *this) {
   assert (! empty_stack (this));
   printf("Stack size: %lu\n", this->size);
   return this->data[this->size--];
}
```

Comment: How does it fail? Can you add the output? What is `stack_item`?

Comment: And you should check range of size. Provide more code.

Comment: You might be failing at the assert, which means your empty_stack function might be faulty(returning false). The other thing to consider is, your stack_item *data might  not be constructed correctly. Post the error and how the stack is being populated and checked.

Comment: I added more code as requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what you mean by "fail".

There are numerous reasons it could fail, such as (by no means exhaustive):

- code for pushing data is incorrect.
- you haven't created a big enough capacity.
- you haven't pushed enough items to pop (stack underflow).

The *first* thing you should do is create a `dump_stack` function for debugging, along the lines of:

```
void dump_stack (char *desc, stack *this) {
    printf ("%s: size/capacity: %lu/%lu\n",
        desc, this->size, this->capacity);
    for (size_t idx = 0; idx < this->size; idx++) {
        // print out this->data[idx], depends on data type
    }
}
```

This will greatly assist in figuring out where your problem lies, if you call it after each stack operation (push, pop, peek, clear, dup, rot, 2dup, 3rot, and so on).

---

Now that you've added some more code, there's a few things you need to look at.

First, your `stack_item` type. Unless this is exactly the same size as `char`, your memory allocation functions are incorrect. For example, if it's a four-byte integer, you will need to allocate four times as much memory as you currently are. This can be fixed by multiplying the allocations by `sizeof(stack_item)`.

You've done this with the initial `calloc` call (because you have to provide a size for that) but not in the subsequent `realloc` ones.

---

Second, in your `realloc_stack` function, you really should `assert` before doing the `memset`. If, for some reason, the reallocation fails, it's not a good idea to do *anything* to the memory.

---

Third, relying on `assert` to catch errors that may or may not happen at runtime is a bad idea. That's because `assert` typically does nothing in non-debug code (based on `NDEBUG`) so, if you run out of memory, you're not going to catch that. You probably need to provide your own error handling stuff in conjunction with `exit()` (for example).

I'm also not really a big fan of library-type code pulling the rug out from underneath you if it has a problem - I always prefer to have it return an indication to the caller and let *that* decide what to do (that's why I'll never use `GMP` in production code since it does exactly that when it runs out of memory).

---

Fourth, using `calloc` and `memset` here is almost certainly a waste since your code knows where the stack end is based on `size`. Whether those entries above `size` but below `capacity` are set to `0` or some arbitrary value is irrelevant since you'll never use them without first setting them to something (with a push operation).

Comment: Pretty good generalization for an AI bot :)

Comment: Thanks for the help and direction, it is much appreciated.